# Awkward notation in Bert Mendelson's "Intro to Topology" - supremum of union of difference between functions

Tags: metric-spaces, notation

I'm looking at Bert Mendelson's "Introduction to Topology" (3rd edition, 1975: Dover pubs) and I am having difficulty understanding the reason for the complexity of his (horribly cumbersome) notation in exercise 5 of section 2 of chapter 2 (Metric Spaces) as follows:

"Let $X'$ be the set of all bounded functions $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$. For $f, g \in X'$ define:
$$d'(f,g) = \operatorname {l.u.b} \cup_{x \in [a,b]} \{|f(x) - g(x)|\}$$

Prove that $(X',d')$ is a metric space."

In this context "bounded" just means that there is a real $K$ such that $|f(x) \le K$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Now I glanced at this first time into this book and casually brushed it aside thinking: oh yes I've seen this before in the context of W.A. Sutherland's "Introduction to Metric and Topological Spaces" (Oxford, 1975) where we have the following definition:

"Example $2.2.8$: Let $A$ be the set of all bounded functions $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$. Given two points $f$ and $g$ in $A$, let
$$d(f,g) = \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x) - g(x)|$$"

which is, basically, the greatest difference between $f$ and $g$ over the domain of interest $[a,b]$.

Now I'm looking back at Mendelson's definition and wondering: is there actually any logical difference between these two definitions? It seems that Mendelson is *also* just trying to set up a distance function which is no more complicated than "the greatest difference between $f$ and $g$ on $[a,b]$".

Is Mendelson just clumsy in his notation here, or is there a subtle reason why he needs to include that $\cup$ in his notation? I can't see what it's there for.

Comment: The $\bigcup$ looks wrong, and should be omitted. The *lub* is taken over all reals $x\in[a,b]$. It's basically meaningless to take unions of real numbers. (It's meaningful to join the sets that represent reals concretely, but that operation has no significance for real analysis.)

Comment: @BrianO: On the contrary, the $\bigcup$ is correct. He is taking the union of a collection of singleton sets of real numbers.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ohh the curly braces around the values not the arguments $x$. Ok I didn't need a telescope but honestly I thought it was abuse of notation. It's terribly fussy  compared to what humans typically write – namely, the second expression OP reproduces.

Comment: @BrianO: Sutherland’s is certainly more readable; it would be interesting to know what on earth prompted Mendelson to express the set as a union of singletons!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I know! An irrelevant notion and symbol (union), and then a subscript on *that*... Of course it's *not incorrect*, but $\bigcup_{a\in A}\{a\}$ is a pretty awkward name for $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His definition is harder to read, but his notation is correct. He has an instance of

$$\bigcup_{x\in A}C_x\,,$$

where $A=[a,b]$, and $C_x=\{|f(x)-g(x)|\}$ for each $x\in[a,b]$. By definition

$$\begin{align*}
\bigcup_{x\in A}C_x&=\bigcup\big\{C_x:x\in A\big\}\\
&=\{y:\exists x\in A\,(y\in C_x)\}\,.\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$

In his context $(1)$ becomes

$$\big\{y:\exists x\in[a,b]\,\left(y\in\{|f(x)-g(x)|\}\right)\big\}\,,$$

which is equal to

$$\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in[a,b]\}\,.$$

Comment: So the definition as given by Mendelson is, as I suspected, merely a tediously fussy and cumbersome way of presenting exactly the same metric as Sutherland presents using rather more streamlined and intuitively obvious notation?

Comment: @PrimeMover: Yes, the two are exactly equivalent. It’s possible that Mendelson actually had a reason for expressing it that way, but I’d have to go through the book to have any hope of guessing what it might have been.